# Generate total property sold for given postcode

Tags: javascript, programming-challenge, node.js, axios

I had to implement the below as a coding challenge.

There are two http endpoints. The first http endpoints returns a list of postcodes. The second http endpoint takes a postcode as a parameter and returns the prices, commission and a discount, which includes percentage discount which should remove to the commission if the number of sales is greater than or equal to `number_required_for_discount`

The goal is to calculate the total number of sales minus the commission, plus the percentage discount if the number of sales exceeds a certain amount and output the results to a csv file called `total_sales.csv` with the headers `id`, `total`

I think the main thing I would like feedback on is the structure of the code and the multiple http calls, which then are used within the functions to get the data. Due to the async await syntax the program is a bit slow but I don't know if that is just the result of making the http calls in order to get the data,

The data from the first endpoint looks like the following:

```json
[
"SW202JR",
"NW152PQ",
...
]
```

The data from the second endpoint looks like the following:

```json
{
"id": "2278",
"postcode": "SW202JR",
"discount": {
"number_required_for_discount": 15,
"commision_discount": 5
},
"sales": [
{
"price": 275000,
"commission": 2750
},
{
"price": 650150,
"commission": 12000
},
...
]
}
```

The csv should look like the following

```
id,total
2278,2577545
NW152PQ,4600545
```

Below is my implementation

```javascript
const path = require("path");
const axios = require("axios");
const csvWriter = require("csv-writer");

const URL = process.env.ENDPOINT;

const getPostcodes = async () => {
  const response = await axios.get(URL);

  return response.data;
};

const getPostcodeData = async () => {
  const postcodes = await getPostcodes();
  let result = [];
  for (let postcode of postcodes) {
    let response = await axios.get(`${URL}/${postcode}`);
    result.push(response.data);
  }
  return result;
};

const calculateSales = async () => {
  const results = await getPostcodeData();
  let data = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
    let total = 0;
    let commission = 0;

    for (result of results[i].sales) {
      total += result.price;
      commission += result.commission;
    }

    const discount =
      results[i].sales.length >=
      results[i].discount.number_required_for_discount
        ? commission - (results[i].discount.commision_discount / 100) * commission
        : commission;
    data.push({
      id: results[i].id,
      total: total - Math.round(discount),
    });
  }
  return data;
};

const generateCSV = async () => {
  const salesData = await calculateSales();
  const writer = csvWriter.createObjectCsvWriter({
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, "total_sales.csv"),
    header: [
      { id: "id", title: "id" },
      { id: "total", title: "total" },
    ],
  });

  writer.writeRecords(salesData).then(() => {
    console.log("Done!");
  });
};

generateCSV();
```

Answer (score 1):

### send requests all in once *may* boost the performance

```javascript
  let result = [];
  for (let postcode of postcodes) {
    let response = await axios.get(`${URL}/${postcode}`);
    result.push(response.data);
  }
```

```javascript
  let result = (await Promise.all(postcodes.map(postcode => axios.get(`${URL}/${postcode}`)))).map(response => response.data);
```

But if it is possible, I would suggest re-design the API so you can get batch data in a single request.

### Avoid calculate money using floating point numbers

```javascript
commission - (results[i].discount.commision_discount / 100) * commission
```

floating point errors may be danger here. You may got something like 7.4399999999999995.